# How do I make a Youtube video start playing at a specific time?

Tags: support

I'm embedding/linking to a Youtube video in posts on this site, is there some way to have the video start playing at a specific point in the video?  I'd like to highlight the relevant portion by having it automatically start at the bit that I'm asking/answering about.

Answer (score 11):

Yes, you can make links to/embed Youtube videos in such a way that they'll start playing at a specified timestamp.  A Youtube link generally looks like this:

> `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-admz4bNq4`

To have it start playing at a specific point, add a "#t=XmYs" replacing the X and Y with the number of minutes and seconds into the video.  For example:

> `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s-admz4bNq4#t=01m55s`

Alternatively, you can: (Thanks Xantec!)

1. Play the video.
2. Pause it at the relevant time.
3. Right-click the video.
4. Click 'Copy video URL at current time'.
5. Paste into your post.

Comment: You can also get the video to where you want it, pause it, then right-click the video timeline and select "Copy video URL at current time"

Comment: @Xantec new one on me, I've been hand modifying the URL all this time :P  Thanks!